# UI-Testing Google Maps Marker Icons

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-espresso, android-uiautomator

I'm trying to assert in my UI test (using either Espresso or UI Automator) that the markers displayed on the map are assigned the correct icons. So far I'm only able to find markers using UI Automator which gives me back a `UiObject` which I can't use to fetch back the icon or overlay values. What could be a way to achieve that?